# Continuous read id rfid

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

I have a project for my school work, to read an Id card to `RFID RDM6300`
this is my code

```
import serial

class Reader(object):
"""The RFID reader class. Reads cards and returns their id"""

def __init__(self, port_name, baudrate, string_length, timeout=1):
    """Constructor

    parameters:
    port_name : the device name of the serial port
    baudrate: baudrate to read at from the serial port
    string_length: the length of the string to read
    timeout: how to long to wait for data on the port
    """
    self.port = serial.Serial(port_name, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)
    self.string_length = string_length

def read(self):
    """Read from self.port"""
    rcv = self.port.read(self.string_length)

    if not rcv:
        return None

    try:
        # note : data from the RFID reader is in HEX. We'll return
        # as int.
        tag = { "raw" : rcv,
                "mfr" : int(rcv[1:5], 16),
                "id" : int(rcv[5:11], 16),
                "chk" : int(rcv[11:13], 16)}

        print "READ CARD : %s" % tag['id']

        return Card(tag)
    except:
        return None

class Card(object):

def __init__(self, tag):
    self.tag = tag

def get_id(self):
    """Return the id of the tag"""
    return self.tag['id']

def get_mfr(self):
    """Return the mfr of the tag"""
    return self.tag['mfr']

def get_chk(self):
    """Return the checksum of the tag"""
    return self.tag['chk']


def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.get_id())

def is_valid(self):
    """Uses the checksum to validate the RFID tag"""
    i2 = 0
    checksum = 0

    for i in range(0, 5):
        i2 = 2 * i
        checksum ^= int(self.tag.raw[i2 + 1:i2 + 3], 16)

    return checksum == tag['chk']
```

but the result is that it continues reading the exact same id again and again
[Screenshot of the same id repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n96vX.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Yeah thanks for fixed it

Comment: Only the first class is fixed.

Comment: Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: @KlausD. help me please

Answer (score 1):

This thread is really old... I don't know if you figured this out or not but maybe the next guy who stumbles across this will find this useful.  The reason you get the card read over and over is that the RDM6300 continually sends data as long as the card is within proximity of the antenna.  There are no delays.  Thus your serial buffer fills up and your program reads from the buffer one entry at a time... Ideally you should read one entry from the serial buffer and then discard the rest by clearing the buffer... or probably better read one entry, allow time for whatever actions you want to take based on the card id, and then clear the buffer when your code is ready for another entry... or after a realistic amount of time between card reads.